# Combobox doubles the value when populated by a database

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Im using C# Winforms and SQL Server as my database.

In my `Combobox_Leave` Event, it will populate other `Combobox` with the text value of the previous

This is one of my `Combobox_Leave` Event, it is similar with other `Combobox`

```
private void cmbPItem_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=" + ip + "," + port + "; Database=records; User ID=" + sqlid + "; Password=" + sqlpass + ""))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT DISTINCT [Brand]
                                                        FROM [dbo].[products] WHERE Item LIKE '" + cmbPItem.Text + "'", conn))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                cmbPBrand.Items.Clear();
                for (int b = 0; b < dt.Rows.Count; b++)
                {
                    cmbPBrand.Items.Add(dt.Rows[b][0].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT DISTINCT [Manufacturer]
                                                        FROM [dbo].[products] WHERE Item LIKE '" + cmbPItem.Text + "'", conn))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                cmbPMan.Items.Clear();
                for (int m = 0; m < dt.Rows.Count; m++)
                {
                    cmbPMan.Items.Add(dt.Rows[m][0].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT DISTINCT [Car]
                                                        FROM [dbo].[products] WHERE Item LIKE '" + cmbPItem.Text + "'", conn))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                cmbPCar.Items.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    cmbPCar.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT DISTINCT [Year]
                                                        FROM [dbo].[products] WHERE Item LIKE '" + cmbPItem.Text + "'", conn))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                cmbPYr.Items.Clear();
                for (int y = 0; y < dt.Rows.Count; y++)
                {
                    cmbPYr.Items.Add(dt.Rows[y][0].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

And the output is like this

[image]

When the user click on the second `Combox`, in this example the `cmbPBrand`. It populates the `Combobx` with duplicated values. But when the user click another `Combobox`, not choosing any entry from `cmbPBrand`. The values are not duplicated.

[image]

Another example of duplicated values.

[image]

In this the `cmbPYr` is clicked after the selection from the `cmbPItem`. It duplicates the `DISTINCT` values.

Note that this happens when the user `CLICK` the second `Combobox`. And Im using `Leave` Event for my `Combobox`.

I also tried adding `MouseClick` and `MouseDown` and `Enter` and `SelectedIndexChanged` Events. But it still duplicate the values.

EDIT:

When using the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Brand,Manufacturer,Car,Year FROM [dbo].[products] WHERE Item LIKE 'BRAKE PADS'
```

Where cmbPItem.Text, for example, is `BRAKE PADS`.

[image]

It will query almost 675 rows.

[image]

EDIT: As for Kevin suggestion. This is code is for Brand `ComboBox` only, but it still show duplicate values.

```
private void cmbProd_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    itemValue(cmbPItem.Text); }

private void itemValue(string sitem) {
    getBrand(sitem); }

private void getBrand(string sitem) {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT DISTINCT [Brand] FROM [dbo].[products] WHERE Item = @Item"))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Item", sitem));
        populateBrand(cmbPBrand, cmd);
    } }

private void populateBrand(ComboBox cmb, SqlCommand cmd) {
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=" + ip + "," + port + "; Database=records; User ID=" + sqlid + "; Password=" + sqlpass + ""))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                cmb.Items.Clear();
                for (int b = 0; b < dt.Rows.Count; b++)
                {
                    cmb.Items.Add(dt.Rows[b][0].ToString());
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    } }
```

Comment: I can't see any problem in the code u wrote, please write the full code

Comment: The is the full code when I populate the combobox.

Comment: Does it happened when populate ? or when fire an event ? **Edit** Why don't you use a single PS for getting all rows based on ur condition ?

Comment: When I tried adding a breakpoint at `SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)` or `sda.Fill(dt)` in my code. At the `If condition` the next step will go back to the start of the event, at `using (SqlConnection...)` then will go over again the whole block. EDIT: What do you mean by PS? Sorry I'm not that familiar.

Comment: You mean the `using (SqlConnection...)` nest? Yes

Comment: It was my fault. sorry

Comment: side not : did u consider to use something like : `using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT DISTINCT Brand,Manufacturer,Car,Year
                                                        FROM [dbo].[products] WHERE Item LIKE '" + cmbPItem.Text + "'", conn))` instead of 4 statements ? and I would suggest to use comboBox `SelectedIndexChanged` as an event instead of `Leave` event

Comment: Yes but it will return almost the whole data. Ill update my question with the query output. I did tried using `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: It's clear that the query returns the exact what u r asking for. If you want more specific results, then you should add more than one statement, like an example, car, brand and year. then it'll return more specific !

Comment: That is why I have 4 queries that is dedicated for each of the `Combobox`

Comment: Obligatory: Don't do queries this way.  You're opening yourself up to SQL Injection Attacks.  Use a Parameterized query, passing in the criteria you're searching for.  Any time you put input directly into an SQL statement, you're opening the door to an Injection Attack.

Comment: Then you have to assign a query for every comboBox. like the first one will return all values of the BRAKE PADS, the second one will search for a results based on comboBox 1 which was BREAK PADS, and the second one, let us say : CAR, then you will get the results of BREAK PADS for TOYOTA, then define the year, or model ! that's how to get the accurate results. But not with one state.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest tackling the problem from a slightly different angle.

First up, you *definitely* should think about changing those queries to be parameterized.  Like I commented, any time you put raw input directly into a SQL statement, you're opening the door to SQL Injection Attacks.  Even if it's not based on user input, it's still a bad habit to get into.  Doing SQL parameterization isn't hard - it's just one extra line of code.

Next up: Refactor your code.  If I understand you correctly, your code reads like:

```
Event X
{
    13 or so lines to update Combo Box #1
    13 or so lines to update Combo Box #2
    13 or so lines to update Combo Box #3
    13 or so lines to update Combo Box #4
}
Event Y
{
    13 or so lines to update Combo Box #1
    13 or so lines to update Combo Box #2
    13 or so lines to update Combo Box #3
    13 or so lines to update Combo Box #4
}
Event Z
{
    13 or so lines to update Combo Box #1
    13 or so lines to update Combo Box #2
    13 or so lines to update Combo Box #3
    13 or so lines to update Combo Box #4
}
Event ... etc
```

Do some googling and playing around with the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) - it'll help you write cleaner, easier-to-debug code.

When that's said and done?  Then you've got a good way of figuring out what the problem is: put some debug lines in your "UpdateBrandCombo()" function - the *only* place where the Brand combo box is updated (right now, you've got a problem in that any of those events might be updating the combo box, and you don't really have any good way of figuring out what's doing it.)

Something like:

```
Event X
{
    UpdateCombosWithSearch(cmbPItem.Text);
}
// ... later on ...
private void UpdateCombosWithSearch(string searchTerm)
{
    UpdateBrandCombo(searchTerm);
    UpdateMfgCombo(searchTerm);
    UpdateCarCombo(searchTerm);
}
private void UpdateBrandCombo(string searchTerm)
{
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct car from dbo.products where Item like @item");
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("item", searchTerm));
        SetComboBoxUsingQuery(cmbPBrand, sqlCmd);
}
private void SetComboBoxUsingQuery(ComboBox cbx, SqlCommand sqlCmd)
{
    cbx.Items.Clear();
    // code to get a DataTable from the sqlCmd
    // code to read the DataTable and add items to cbx
}
```

See the beauty?  You don't have repetitive code.  Your events all have one line: UpdateCombosWithSearch().  UpdateCombosWithSearch simply calls an Update on each combo box it needs to update.  And each of those functions simply generate an SQL command and pass in which box is to be updated.  The only function that even has any SQL code is the SetComboBoxUsingQuery() function.

So now you can add something like:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Event logged by " + (new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace()).ToString());
```

... to one of those functions - so you can figure out just where/when/how your update code is being called.

Comment: I will do this tomorrow and will be back for my improvement.

Comment: I did something a like to the template you share. It somehow solve my problem. What I have observe is, when I click/enter inside the `Combobox` before clicking the `DropDown` arrow it will not display the duplicated values. But when I click the `DropDown` arrow first, it shows duplicated values.

Comment: I have solved the issue by adding `if (!cmbPBrand.Items.Contains(dt.Rows[b][0].ToString()))` inside my `FOR Loop`. Thanks for giving me additional information, just started a couple of months with minimal knowledge to this developing thing, this will help me in the future.

Comment: No problem - and the best of luck to you.  Also, something you should check out: "Clean Code" by Robert 'Uncle Bob' Martin.  It's the book that helped me become a better developer, and is probably the #1 most influential book in the programming field.  It goes over SRP, and a lot of other programming concepts to make clean code.